# How to properly format my Python structure?

Tags: python

This is the read output

```
['multi_index', ' int64']
['multi_no', ' int64']
['name_class', ' string']
['name_event', ' string']
.....
```

I want every line to have this format

```
('multi_index', pa.int64()),
('multi_no', pa.int64())

with open("out.txt") as file:
    with open("pravi.txt", 'w') as f2:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip().split(":")
            f2.write('{} pa.{}'.format(line))
```

How to rewrite last line of my code?

Comment: Consider using pickle or json to write your ouput

Comment: @Chris_Rands That won't help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to question why you'd need such an output -- it looks like you're generating code with a script while you could be just running the code instead, but rReverse engineering" your current output

```
['multi_index', ' int64']
['multi_no', ' int64']
['name_class', ' string']
['name_event', ' string']
```

, I think your input file looks like

```
multi_index: int64
multi_no: int64
name_class: string
name_event: string
```

If so, you're almost there:

```
import io

input_file = io.StringIO("""
multi_index: int64
multi_no: int64
name_class: string
name_event: string
""".strip())

for line in input_file:
    name, type = line.strip().split(': ', 1)
    print(f"('{name}', pa.{type}()),")
```

outputs

```
('multi_index', pa.int64()),
('multi_no', pa.int64()),
('name_class', pa.string()),
('name_event', pa.string()),
```

so the only real change is to split using `': '` to munch that space out of the type and printing out properly.